# Adding validations to see if radio button is not selected, all the questions is compulsory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code in which there are 5 questions. I want that all 5 questions should be answered, in case any questions is not filled, user gets validation.

```html
question 1
<ul class="option">
   <li>  <input type="radio" name="question1" id="sd1" value="1">Strongly Disagree</li>
    <li> <input type="radio" name="question1" id="d1" value="2">Disagree</li>
     <input type="radio" name="question1" id="n1" value="3">Neither Agree Nor Dis<li>agree</li>
  <li>  <input type="radio" name="question1" id="a1" value="4">Agree</li>
  <li>   <input type="radio" name="question1" id="sa1" value="5">Strongly Agree
</li></ul>
<br/><br/>

question 2
<ul class="option">
    <li> <input type="radio" name="question2" id="sd2" value="1">Strongly Disagree</li>
    <li> <input type="radio" name="question2" id="d2" value="2">Disagree</li>
   <li>  <input type="radio" name="question2" id="n2" value="3">Neither Agree Nor Disagree</li>
   <li> <input type="radio" name="question2" id="a2" value="4">Agree</li?
   <li>  <input type="radio" name="question2" id="sa2" value="5">Strongly Agree
</li></ul>
<br/><br/>
```

javascript code is

```
// Delegate submit action
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {

    var validate = true;
    var unanswered = new Array();

    // Loop through available sets
    $('.option').each(function () {
        // Question text
        var question = $(this).prev();
        // Validate
        if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
            // Didn't validate ... dispaly alert or do something
            unanswered.push(question.text());
            question.css('color', 'red'); // Highlight unanswered question
            validate = false;
        }
    });

    if (unanswered.length > 0) {
        msg = "Please answer the following questions:\n" + unanswered.join('\n'); 
        alert(msg);
    }
    return validate;
});
```

I'm getting alert as a blank, only one line is written please answer following questions but no questions number inside

Comment: `console.log(question, question.text())`

Comment: sorry i dint understand, where to write this?

Comment: This is called __debugging__ and you should write it where you want to check values.

Comment: can you show the html of your questions

Comment: i have pasted the html part above javascript part, please check and help me out

Comment: i am asking for the html tag of your questions as it is not there in the above posted html

Comment: if it is without any tag than thats the issue.wrap your question inside any tag and it sould start working.do something like <div>Question1</div>

Answer (score 2):

Just put your questions in a tag ( I have put it in span tag ) with an unique id and it should work with your code.

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {

    var validate = true;
    var unanswered = new Array();

    // Loop through available sets
    $('.option').each(function () {
        // Question text
        var question = $(this).prev();
        // Validate
        if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
            // Didn't validate ... dispaly alert or do something
            //alert(JSON.stringify($(this).siblings()));
            unanswered.push(question.text());
            question.css('color', 'red'); // Highlight unanswered question
            validate = false;
        }
    });

    if (unanswered.length > 0) {
    //alert(unanswered);
        msg = "Please answer the following questions:\n" + unanswered.join('\n'); 
        alert(msg);
    }
    return validate;
});
```

```html
<body>
<form id='form' action='#' method='post'>

<span id='q1'>question 1</span>
<ul class="option">
   <li>  <input type="radio" name="question1" id="sd1" value="1">Strongly Disagree</li>
    <li> <input type="radio" name="question1" id="d1" value="2">Disagree</li>
     <input type="radio" name="question1" id="n1" value="3">Neither Agree Nor Dis<li>agree</li>
  <li>  <input type="radio" name="question1" id="a1" value="4">Agree</li>
  <li>   <input type="radio" name="question1" id="sa1" value="5">Strongly Agree
</li></ul>
<br/><br/>

<span id='q2'>question 2</span>
<ul class="option">
    <li> <input type="radio" name="question2" id="sd2" value="1">Strongly Disagree</li>
    <li> <input type="radio" name="question2" id="d2" value="2">Disagree</li>
   <li>  <input type="radio" name="question2" id="n2" value="3">Neither Agree Nor Disagree</li>
   <li> <input type="radio" name="question2" id="a2" value="4">Agree</li>
   <li>  <input type="radio" name="question2" id="sa2" value="5">Strongly Agree
</li></ul>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Sonal Kakkar Chawla is the answer working. If yes, please accept as answer or solution otherwise tell me where it is still a problem for you.